# How to compute coordinates of start/end points of a ArcByCenterPoint?

Tags: geometry, gis, formula, gml-geographic-markup-lan

Given an ArcByCenterPoint, defined by:

1. center position (lat,lon in WGS84)
2. radius (meters)
3. startAngle (degrees)
4. endAngle (degrees)

how can we compute the position (lat, lon) of start/end points? I'm looking for a formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find appropriate formulas in the section **Destination point given distance and bearing from start point** [here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)
Excerpt:

```
Formula:
φ2 = asin( sin φ1 ⋅ cos δ + cos φ1 ⋅ sin δ ⋅ cos θ )     
λ2 = λ1 + atan2( sin θ ⋅ sin δ ⋅ cos φ1, cos δ − sin φ1 ⋅ sin φ2 )
where   
φ is latitude, λ is longitude, 
θ is the bearing (clockwise from north), 
δ is the angular distance d/R; 
d being the distance travelled, R the earth’s radius
```

Comment: Thanks this did the job. Just have to pay attention to transform the input to radians.

Answer (score 0):

If you want extreme accuracy try using [GeographicLib](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/) and the formula in the source code under the hood of the [Direct Problem](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/scripts/geod-calc.html#direct) at the "Geodesic calculations for an ellipsoid done right" web page.